# Build a Query in MySQL to Find Customer Name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have below SQL statemet in MySQL but the problem it only accept one string so if I have a customer called John Mathews they can type jo or joh or john to find it but when they type john ma or john mat it will return zero row. Similarly when they type john 4455667 (where 4455667 is the conatct details).

How can I fix it please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.customer_id, CONCAT(IFNULL(titles.title_name, ""), " " , customers.first_name, " ", customers.middle_name, " ", customers.last_name) AS customer_name, MAX(DATE(advance_orders.delivery_date)) AS last_order
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN titles ON titles.title_id = customers.title
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.company_id = customers.company
LEFT JOIN job_titles ON job_titles.job_title_id = customers.job_title
LEFT JOIN customers_contact ON customers_contact.customer_id = customers.customer_id
LEFT JOIN advance_orders ON advance_orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
WHERE first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR middle_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR last_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR customers_contact.contact_details LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR companies.company_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR job_titles.job_title_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
ORDER BY customer_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
WHERE first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR middle_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR last_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
```

try:

```
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ',middle_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
```

of course, you can extend the logic to the other OR:

```
OR customers_contact.contact_details LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR companies.company_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
OR job_titles.job_title_name LIKE CONCAT('%', param_find ,'%')
```

if you need.

Regards

Comment: still unable to find john mat (for John mathew). Anything after the space will result to null row

Comment: Right, the problem IS the space. Look at the updated answer.